# On insert to SERVER1 or SERVER2 database table trigger a different insert to SERVER3 database table 

Tags: php, mysql

**SERVER1** = Shopping Cart1
**SERVER2** = Shopping Cart2
**SERVER3** = Reporting

I have 3 servers currently, 2 are shopping carts (**SERVER1** & **SERVER2**) and 1 is for reporting and manually entering orders (**SERVER3**).

On **SERVER3** I Have a table for orders that are manually entered (This table has a little more information than the order tables on **SERVER1** & **SERVER2** becuase of some processing that is done after a order is placed.).  I want to somehow import the information from the order tables on **SERVER1** & **SERVER2** on the fly to **SERVER3** so these orders can follow the same process.

**
**Previously**
**

We previously used to import this by a CSV to the **SERVER3** order table (download new rows to a CSV and then import this CSV to the **SERVER3** table using PHP/mySQL)

**
**Thoughts**
**

1)
Would the easiest way to simply add PHP/mySQL code on **SERVER1** & **SERVER2** to also update this table on **SERVER3**?  I would rather not do this becuase I want this process to be fast and independent.  If for whatever reason **SERVER3** goes down I would not want it to affect ordering on **SERVER1** & **SERVER2**.

2) I thought about using triggers but they only work on the existing mySQL connection. I replicate the data from **SERVER1** & **SERVER2** to separate mySQL instances on **SERVER3** (mySQL can only have 1 master hence the multiple instances) but is there any way to utilize a mySQL trigger to change ports and do the update that way?

3) The only other thing I could think of was creating a PHP cronjob to check these tables but then this truly wouldn't happen on the fly but whenever I had the cronjob running.

Maybe I am just thinking way to much, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: multiple master is possible, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: Have you thought about implementing a sender on s1 & s2 using curl that will post to a receiver on s3, then the receiver checks and inserts the new record.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a Trigger, but writing/updating into a `FEDERATED` engine table, it's not beautiful, but solve your problem.

More about `FEDERATED` engine [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html), this engine creates a kind of local table of a remote server table.